# Как передать заполненную форму в приложение почты по умолчанию

Tags: c#, uwp

В windows phone 8 такое можно реализовать с помощью:

```
EmailComposeTask compose = new EmailComposeTask();
compose.To = "director356@mail.ru";
compose.Body = "Здравствуйте";
compose.Show();
```

Как это сделать в windows 10 UWP? (Нашел способ отправки емеила но там в форму надо ввести пароль и логин, а мне надо чтобы это данные передавались в приложение почты)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А чем Вас [стандартный UWP метод создания и отправки email](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/uwp/contacts-and-calendar/sending-email) не устраивает?

```
private async Task ComposeEmail(string emailAddress, string subject, string messageBody)
{
    var emailMessage = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailMessage();
    emailMessage.Body = messageBody;
    var emailRecipient = new Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailRecipient(emailAddress);
    emailMessage.To.Add(emailRecipient);
    emailMessage.Subject = subject;
    await Windows.ApplicationModel.Email.EmailManager.ShowComposeNewEmailAsync(emailMessage);
}
```

P.S. Вообще, документация у Microsoft весьма неплоха, нужно только ей пользоваться ;)

Answer (score 0):

Можете попробовать так:

```
await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("mailto:?to=example@mail.com&subject=The subject&body=body message"));
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло! Только в теле не получается на новую строку переходить \n не помогает, но все равно большое спасибо)